# Issue with prefetching images in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I'm using Kingfisher framework to prefetched images but overtime I get nothing in completedResources. It always prints "These resources are prefetched: []" I first fetch number of URLs in an albumImagePathArray, which are fetched successfully but when I call the downloadImages() method it shows "These resources are prefetched: []". The link to the Kingfisher framework is: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Here's my code that I've written:

```
func downloadImages() {
    if(self.albumImagePathArray.isEmpty == false) {
        //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
            let urls = self.albumImagePathArray.map { NSURL(string: $0)! }
            let prefetcher = ImagePrefetcher(urls: urls, optionsInfo: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: {
                (skippedResources, failedResources, completedResources) -> () in
                print("These resources are prefetched: \(completedResources)")
            })
        prefetcher.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: print  `skippedResources` and `failedResources` see if they are are already cached  or fail to be downloaded

Comment: Yes, it shows in the skippedResources. Thanks!